# Increasing video memory on an older macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, video-adapter

I have a 2,1 macbook with 4GB ram of which 64mb are dedicated to the video card. Can I increase this to at least 512?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, VRAM is soldered on/in somewhere.  I suppose you *could*, if you had the know how, but the short answer is, no.

Edit:  That is, VRAM is not (usually) taken from the pool of "available RAM," it's actually separate RAM entirely.  And dedicated to the GPU, only.

Comment: well that royally sucks

Comment: Actually, MacBooks tend to have integrated graphics, which do not have separate VRAM - they do use the same RAM as everything else. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to increase the RAM allotment.